# "site's header" – is that correct?

Tags: possessives

Sometimes I come across constructions like "site's header" or "site's navigation", but as I know the possessive case in most cases shouldn't be used with inanimate nouns. So my question is – are those correct collocations and might they be used in some more formal contexts?

Comment: *"as I know the possessive case in most cases shouldn't be used with inanimate nouns"* - where did you hear that?  You can certainly use the possessive case with inanimate nouns.

Comment: Well, I've read that it might be used with countries' or cities' names (America's), nouns denoting time (year's) and some other words, but not with any inanimate noun.

Comment: Some writers consider it bad style, but in practice we certainly use the possessive with inanimate nouns: *the screwdriver's handle, the philosophy's appeal, the site's header*, etc.  We use *of* more often with inanimate nouns - *the handle of the screwdriver* but it isn't a rule that you have to.

Comment: It seems that my book is "overly correct". Thank you.

Comment: ...the river's source, the road's curve, the wind's roar, the wall's color...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> site's header
>   site's navigation

are correct and refer to either the site's top/beginning or possibly some picks used to move through the site.

Using possessives with inanimate nouns often happens

> The *bike's tires* need air.
>   The *teddy bear's* fur is wet.
>
> The *site's header* is an ugly color.
>   The *site's navigation* is not intuitive.